# How do you renumber sheets in a large Excel workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

With an Excel workbook with a number of sheets in a workbook, it can be difficult to rename the sheets manually if you insert or delete a sheet:

```
 Intro-A   <<== Skip this one, please
 Intro-B   <<== Skip 
 Intro-C   <<== Skip 
 Main-1    <<== Start renumbering here
 Main-2
 Main-3
           <<== Deleted
 Main-5
 Main-6...
```

and so on.  If I insert or delete a sheet in the sequence, I have to renumber the sheets manually.  How can this be done with VBA to save time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use A Macro

I found the [answer on a blog](https://neseef.com/2019/03/31/excel-rename-multiple-worksheets-vbs/), "Notes of a Sysadmin" from Neseef.com, which did most of what I need. I added the ability to skip the introductory sheets, prompt for the prefix, and avoid name collisions that occur when a sheet has been inserted.

The macro doesn't need to be in the same workbook. *This means you do not need to re-save your workbook as an `*.xlsm` file.* It can be in a different workbook, as long as both are open at the same time.

- ⚠ **Caution:** **Save** the Workbook before beginning work!
- You can add the macro below to your workbook, **or** you can create a New workbook -- save the workbook that has the macro as `*.xlsm` (Macro-Enabled Workbook).
- As usual, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> : Insert : Module and paste the macro below.
- Return to the workbook with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>.
- Run the macro with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> and "OK".

```vb
' ** Rename Sheets ** 2020-09-10
' If you need to renumber your sheets sequentially, with a prefix,
' Like "AA-1, AA-2, AA-3" or "XX-A, XX-1, XX-2"..
' Suggested by this method: https://neseef.com/2019/03/31/excel-rename-multiple-worksheets-vbs/
' Use only on saved worksheets.  As-is.

Sub RenamingSheets()

Dim myPrefx As String

myStartSheet = InputBox("What sheet to start with? (1=first)", "Renaming Sheets")
myPrefx = InputBox("What prefix should the sheet names have?  (`BG-`, `Sheet`, etc.)", "Renaming Sheets")
myNum = InputBox("What's the first number you want to name the sheets?", "Renaming Sheets")

'Clear the names so there are no collisions
'(Temporarily set the name to a hopefully unique name)

For ws = myStartSheet To Worksheets.Count
    Sheets(ws).name = "Foo" & Worksheets.Count + ws
Next ws

'Now renumber

For ws = myStartSheet To Worksheets.Count
    Sheets(ws).name = myPrefx & myNum
    myNum = myNum + 1
Next ws

End Sub
```